# Various Troubles with VBA (Excel Maros)

Tags: excel, vba

I would briefly like to start off with I have never touched VBA let alone excel macros until a couple days ago.

I need to transfer and convert data of 1000 rows (4 columns) from one sheet (Sheet 1) to another (Sheet 2).

A quick description of what I'm given, each row is an object, I have 4 columns.
The first one (column) is the Object ID, the second one is the Object name, the third one explain the what of the object and the final column explains the how. This is a very simplified version as explaining the entire project would be complicated.

On the second sheet, I have 6000 rows all with the object's IDs and Names however the What and How are missing.

My goal is to take the what and how of an object from this sheet, convert the wording to a form in which the second sheet accepts and make sure it gets added to the proper ID.

I have tried multiple code samples I have found online to try and select and organize into tables (arrays) the information from the first sheet, I failed miserably.

**Converting the What and How**

The second sheet has a very strict format in which everything can be written. In my mind (Lua is my main language), I would have a dictionary or table with all possible ways of the How/What could be written on the first sheet and checking each one to see if they match then change it to the corresponding sheet 2 format. Let me show you. (This is the what. There'd be another table for the how which I'll show below)

```lua
local MType = {
    ["Industrial"] = {"MILPRO : Industrial","Industrial"};
    ["Public Saftey"] = {"MILPRO : Public Saftey", "Public Saftey"};
    ["Military"] = {"MILPRO : Military","Military"};
    ["Paddling"] = {"Recreation : Paddling","Paddling"};
    ["Sporting Goods"] = {"Recreation : Sporting Goods","Sporting Goods"};
    ["Outdoor"] = {"Recreation : Outdoor", "Outdoor"};
    ["Hook & Bullet"] = {"Recreation : Hook & Bullet", "Hook & Bullet"};
    ["Marine"] = {"Recreation : Marine","Marine","Marina / Lodge"};
    ["Sailing"] = {"Recreation : Sailing","Sailing"};
    ["Unknown"] = {"UNKNOWN"}
}
```

```lua
local CType = {
    ["Multi-Door"] = {"Multi-Door","Multi-door"};
    ["Dealer & Distributor"] = {"Distributor","Dealer & Distributor"};
    ["Independant Specialty"] = {"Independant Specialty","Specialty"};
    ["OEM"] = {"OEM","OEM - VAR"};
    ["Internal"] = {"Internal","Sales Agency","Repairs Facility"};
    ["Rental"] = {"Rental / Outfitter", "Rental"};
    ["End User"] = {"End User"};
    ["Institution"] = {"Institution","Government Direct"};
    ["Unknown"] = {"UNKNOWN"}
}
```

The first position in each table (table = the curly brackets) is the format in which the second sheet accepts. The rest in the tables is how they might be written in the first sheet. (This is how I imagine this would go down. Idk the functions and limits of VBA)

**Matching the Information to the Proper IDs**

Every object has an ID 6 characters long ranging from 000100 to 999999. When taking information from the first sheet, I need to make sure it gets placed back in the row with the right ID in the second sheet (Note there's 1000 rows on the first sheet and 6000 on the second sheet).

Final notes: The IDs are stored as text and not numbers (If they need to change lmk). Both sheet's information are within tables. I'll probably be using this method for other similar sheet 1s. Any conversions (for the what and how) that fail should be marked down as Unknown.

**A Visual Representation of the 2 Sheets**

[Sheet 1 Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTrdA.png)

[Sheet 2 format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5s9A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a 2 dimensional array to hold all the pairs of one dictionary, then check against each element using a For..Next loop.

```
Sub transcribe()

On Error GoTo Handler

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
Dim ID1 As Range, ID2 As Range
'This is assuming youre working in Sheets 1 and 2
Set WS1 = Sheets(1)
Set WS2 = Sheets(2)
'This is assuming your tables are in these locations
Set ID1 = WS1.Range(WS1.Cells(1, 1), WS1.Cells(10, 1))
Set ID2 = WS2.Range(WS2.Cells(1, 1), WS2.Cells(20, 1))

Dim cellx As Range
Dim rowID1 As Integer
Dim FieldA As String, FieldB As String
Dim IDfound As Boolean
IDfound = True

Dim arrayA(1 To 10, 1) As String
    arrayA(1, 0) = "MILPRO : Industrial"
    arrayA(1, 1) = "Industrial"
    arrayA(2, 0) = "MILPRO : Public Saftey"
    arrayA(2, 1) = "Public Saftey"
    '... etc. You have to complete this array with all the pairs of your dictionary of Field A
    'array(X, 1) holds what you expect to find in table 1, and array(X, 0) holds what you want to write down in table 2.

Dim arrayB(1 To 9, 1) As String
    arrayB(1, 0) = "Multi-Door"
    arrayB(1, 1) = "Multi-Door"
    arrayB(2, 0) = "Distribuitor"
    arrayB(2, 1) = "Dealer & Distribuitor"
    '... etc. You have to complete this array with all the pairs of your dictionary of Field B
    'array(X, 1) holds what you expect to find in table 1, and array(X, 0) holds what you want to write down in table 2.


'Now we sweep each cell in Table 2
For Each cellx In ID2.Cells
    'And we search its ID for a match in Table 1.
    rowID1 = Application.Match(cellx.Value, ID1, 0)
    
    If IDfound = True Then
        'We then write down the values of Field A and B in the found row
        FieldA = ID1.Resize(1).Offset(rowID1 - 1, 2).Value
        FieldB = ID1.Resize(1).Offset(rowID1 - 1, 3).Value
        'And we call a function (see below) to correct their values
        cellx.Offset(0, 2).Value = corrected(FieldA, arrayA, 10)
        cellx.Offset(0, 3).Value = corrected(FieldB, arrayB, 9)
    Else
        cellx.Offset(0, 2).Value = "ID not found"
        cellx.Offset(0, 3).Value = "ID not found"
        IDfound = True
    End If
    
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

Handler:
    IDfound = False
    Resume Next

End Sub
Function corrected(Field As String, arrayX As Variant, UB As Integer) As String
'This is the dictionary-like function
Dim found As Boolean
'We sweep each element in the dictionary array until we find a match
For i = 1 To UB
    If Field = arrayX(i, 1) Then
        corrected = arrayX(i, 0)
        found = True
        Exit Function
        Exit For
    End If
Next
'If no match was found, we will write that down in the result
If found = False Then
    corrected = Field & " - Not found in dictionary"
    Exit Function
End If

'This code should never be reached, its just for foolproofing
corrected = "Error"

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, computer died. Thanks a ton, I'll get to work on adapting it to my Worksheet and I'll get back to you.

Comment: So after some tweaking and molding it's so close to working, however, there's a small kink I can't seem to work out. So the second sheet has significantly more rows than the first sheet (6:1 ratio). Your function works however it fills out the entire second sheet (which obv isnt right). When it comes across a row that should be filled (It's in the second sheet but not the first), it copies the last one over into it. So it looks something like:
Marine
Marine
Marine
Marine
Marine
Outdoor
Outdoor
Outdoor
Marine
Marine

Comment: @jrdonat I edited the code to add an extra clause where if the ID in Table 2 is not found in Table 1, it will write "ID not found".

Comment: Sweet thanks a ton. Saved me thousands of lines of work. Good day and farewell.